# Smooch Rich Messaging on mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, smooch

I'm diving into Smooch.io documentation as I'm interested on rich messaging feature that they offer and I saw the syntax for introducing Action Buttons on mobile apps but how can I achieve this? https://smooch.io/rich-messaging/
(I mean a message containing image/map, text and button)
I'm just asking for the technology needed to implement and how to show it into a "bubble"-message

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the map example, you would need to add custom code to your iOS and Android app. 
Buttons can be sent across all messaging channels that Smooch supports using the button syntax:

```
%[Button Label](http://anyurl.com)
```

Images can be sent across all messaging channels using this syntax:

`![](http://imageurl.com)`

Smooch.io will display your message/image/button in the format that makes the most sense for the end-user, depending on the channel they are viewing it on.

For more information on sending rich medias, checkout the full cheatsheet
http://blog.smooch.io/how-to-make-buttons-images-payments-with-smooch-a-syntax-cheatsheet/

Comment: Thank you @kvgauthier, this really help me. As I found documentation for action buttons, I thought there was a more complex strategy to integrate other components (and I had no idea where to start from)